# How to perform a transaction in Dataverse from PowerApps for Teams

Tags: transactions, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

I'm a bit new to power platform with a classical programming background.
I'm doing a small app in PowerApps for Teams that stores data in the Dataverse. I try to perform very classical transaction: decrease amount of goods in Stocks and simultaneously increase in Sales with collection.patch.

Question: is there a way to do it in transact way?
What I found, is that there is only a way to perform "change set" request in Power Automate flow, and it is not possible at all in Power Apps. Is it correct? How do people create any serious multi-user apps without using transactions? Is there another technique?

I tried to examine Collection.Patch return value. But this is not really a transaction, because if second operation fails, one cannot really rollback the first operation.